# Hydrogen bonding in acetylene and other terminal alkynes

Tags: organic-chemistry, hydrocarbons, hydrogen-bond

My textbook says that hydrogen bonding is possible only when there is acidic hydrogen connected to an electronegative atom like $\ce{N}$, $\ce{O}$ or $\ce{F}$ and a basic lone pair of electrons on another electronegative atom.

Recently, when I was going through a material on organic chemistry online, I read that $\ce{sp}$ hybridised carbon atom is more electronegative than $\ce{sp}^{3}$ hybridised nitrogen atom. Assuming that is true, we can infer that $\ce{sp}$ hybridised C-H bond is more acidic than $\ce{sp}^{3}$ hybridised N-H bond.

I already know that ammonia has strong hydrogen bonding and the nitrogen atom in ammonia is $\ce{sp}^{3}$ hybridised. So I wanted to know if acetylene has strong hydrogen bonding.

I asked my teacher about this but he simply replied by saying 'no'. I tried googling my doubt but couldn't find any resource which gave me a satisfactory answer. I also wanted to know that, if acetylene shows hydrogen bonding, can other terminal alkynes show hydrogen bonding?

Comment: Have you looked up the pKa values of acetylene and ammonia?

Comment: "Assuming that is true, we can infer that sp hybridised C-H bond is more acidic than sp3 hybridised N-H bond." That logic is not compelling.

Comment: Water and HF have *strong* hydrogen bonding. Ammonia is a gas. Bp. 240K compared to 293 and 373. Hydrogen bonds between water and ammonia are strong.

Comment: @Karl Yeah I just checked the pKa values... Saw a drastic difference in those values between acetylene and ammonia

Comment: Still it is true that a C sp is more electronegative than a C sp3. Just think as the situation seen by a charge test approaching it from the two side, or what is seen by the terminal H of acetylene as compared to an H atom in ethane.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%E2%80%93H%C2%B7%C2%B7%C2%B7O_interaction https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi-Stacking_(chemistry)

Comment: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ct300100h https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0022286016304938 https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/23247410/

Comment: Thank you people for the help. I have better clarity now.