Why can't ethyne form hydrogen bonds in water?
I was recently taught about hydrogen bonding and I learnt that a hydrogen atom attached to fluorine, nitrogen, oxygen or a sp-hybridized carbon (EN = 3.25) can get into a hydrogen bond with another electronegative atom. Then why is it that the hydrogens of ethyne, which has a sp-hybridized carbon, can't form H-bonds with the oxygen atoms of water?

:/ This hybridized electronegativity again... I don't think its introduction was as smart as whoever done this thought. Hydrogen bonding is waaaay most common than most people think (you're not alone in this). The bonds get weaker and weaker the further you reach, though.

Dup of https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/143469/hydrogen-bonding-in-acetylene-and-other-terminal-alkynes, though no accepted answer there, either.

acetylene is more soluble in water than ethylene something is going on. Specific H-bonding will be very weak. May I suggest a matrix isolation study of acetylene-water in frozen argon to detect variations in the C-H stretch frequencies.

@jimchmst already been done: https://doi.org/10.1016/0009-2614(83)80699-X

Good it is pay to play. Can you share some info?

According to a matrix isolation study by Engdahl and Nelander,$^1$ acetylene/ethyne does form a hydrogen bond with water. They deposited mixtures of HCCH/DCCD/HCCD and $\ce{H2O}$/$\ce{D2O}$ in solid argon matrices and recorded infrared spectra. The magnitude of the shifts in the C–H vibrations indicated that a $\ce{C\bond{-}H/D\bond{...}O}$ hydrogen bond formed between the acetylene and water molecules.

Engdahl, A.; Nelander, B. The acetylene-water complex. A matrix isolation study. Chem. Phys. Lett. 1983, 100 (2), 129-132. DOI: 10.1016/0009-2614(83)80699-X.

